# How to stack progress bars into one bar with Bulma css

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm trying to create a progress bar which is made up of multiple colours that all add up to fill a singular bar.

I can make 3 individual bars but I'd like to make it similar to the [Bootstrap one](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/progress/#how-it-works)

To make 3 bars I've done:

```
<progress class="progress is-success" value="50" max="100"></progress>
<progress class="progress is-warning" value="35" max="100"></progress>
<progress class="progress is-danger" value="15" max="100"></progress>
```

The end goal being I'd have one bar with the green portion, the yellow portion filling up the next portion and then the red filling out the remainder.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using the progress element, you'll need to create your own progress bar, which would look something like this:

```css
.progress {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

.progress-bar { float: left; }

.progress-bar.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-bar.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-bar.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar orange" style="width:10%;"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar blue" style="width:30%;"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar yellow" style="width:50%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it prettier to achieve this effect with linear-gradient background?